# DTD attribute separator

Tags: xml, dtd

How to set in the DTD to attribute were the value would be divided separator?

```html
<element
  attr="value_1|value_2|value_3|..."
/>
```

Comment: Looks more like XML Schema to me than DTD, right?

Comment: Does: <!ATTLIST element-name attribute-name (en1|en2|..) default-value> not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

With DTD you can't validate elements/attributes text values. You can only define if an element should countain more elements (which ones and in which order) and if an attribute is required or not, its value...

If you need to check an attribute's text value, you should use XML Schema instead of DTD.
You'll need a restriction on attribute's value using a regex pattern to check text value. Something like this should work for you:

```
<xs:attribute name="attribute">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:pattern value="patern here"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```